# How do I create a file of aliases for zsh like I did for Bash?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bash, zsh

I've spent the last few years learning Ubuntu and fallen in love with Bash aliases. I recently got a Macbook Air and I want to use aliases, but MacOS uses zsh by default. I copied my .bash_aliases file from one of my Ubuntu machines to my Macbook and the aliases worked right out of the gate.

The current issue is that I created a new alias and it won't work. On Ubuntu, I just ran `bash` again to start a new session and the new alias was immediately available. Running `zsh` again did not load the new alias and I get `Command not found`.

My `.bash_aliases` looks like this:

```
alias saud='sudo apt update -y'
alias saug='sudo apt upgrade -y'
alias sarm='sudo apt autoremove -y'
alias sai='sudo apt install $1 -y'
alias ll='ls -lh'
alias cba='cat .bash_aliases'
alias nba='sudo nano .bash_aliases'
alias ifc='ifconfig'
alias rsa='sudo service apache2 restart'
alias version='lsb_release -a'
alias scaf='ssh cloud.mydomain.com -p 12345 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -v'
alias ncc='sudo -u www-data php occ'
alias ncr='service mysql restart && service php7.4-fpm restart && service nginx restart'
alias ncs='service mysql status | echo "mysql: " $(grep Active) \
    && service php7.4-fpm status | echo "74fpm: " $(grep Active) \
    && service nginx status | echo "nginx: " $(grep Active)'
```

I didn't get any errors indicating that a syntax issue with the file.

Since the other aliases work fine, why is the new one being ostracized?

Comment: zsh uses different startup files. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/).

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for the insight. It appears that I had previously appended my bash_aliases file to my .zshrc file. That explains why my new addition to the .bash_aliases file didn't work: my Macbook was reading from .zshrc, which didn't contain my newest addition! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In principle starting `zsh` again should work, but you could also just define another alias to re-read your alias file with `rra`:

```
alias rra='source ~/.bash_aliases'
```